# Conversion of datetime to nvarchar(8) in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to convert a `datetime` column to ISO format, as `yyyymmdd`. For example, I would like to be able to convert '13 dec 2018' to '20181213'.

According to [Microsoft's T-SQL Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles), I should be able to do this using

```
convert(nvarchar(8), '13 dec 2018', 112)
```

however this doesn't work - I get the result '13 dec 2', which looks to be nothing more than the original string cut down to 8 characters.

I have also tried using

```
convert(datetime, '13 dec 2018', 112)
```

which gives me the result of 'Dec 13 2018 12:00AM' - again, nothing like what the function is supposed to produce.

What I am doing wrong? I could solve the problem easily enough using `datepart()` and concatenated strings, but I'd rather use the more elegant approach if possible.

Comment: You're starting with a string not a date. `convert(nvarchar(8), convert(date,'13 dec 2018'), 112)` should work.

Comment: Thanks - had a bit of a 'duh' moment, should have realized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine them:

```
convert(nvarchar(8), convert(datetime, '13 dec 2018'), 112)
```

I don't recommend using the format `112` for the first conversion, because it is misleading.  SQL Server is very good at converting without a format.  If you do use one the appropriate one is `106`.

Comment: Thanks, similar to the solution I posted below. Why would you use 106 though? That won't give me the output I'm looking for, which is yyyymmdd, with no intervening characters.

Comment: @Billious . . . Because that is the format for *parsing* the string into a `date`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - because I was entering the date as a string, and not converting it to a datetime value first, it was treating my date as if it were a string. When I handle it this way:

```
convert(nvarchar(8), cast('13 dec 2018' as datetime), 112)
```

I get the expected result, '20181213'.

Answer (score 0):

select convert(nvarchar(8), cast(GETDATE() as datetime), 112) as TodayDate

[image]

Answer (score 0):

YYYYMMDD format can obtain by datetime to varchar format.

```
select convert(varchar(8),convert(datetime, '13 dec 2018'),112)
```

The above query provides the required result